# changing dropdown option SELECTED dynamically

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have this drop down

```
<select class="dropdown"><option value="0">Disabled</option><option value="1">Enabled</option></select>
```

In javascript using query or just plain javascript, I want to dynamically change the value of the select box to that of my div show. here is my div show

Enabled

so if this div is Enabled I should have selected in Enabled option. So the above drop down would be

```
<select class="dropdown"><option value="0">Disabled</option><option value="1" selected>Enabled</option></select>
```

how would I do that? thanks

Comment: What exactly is "div show"? Is "show" the class of your div? How is the text in the div changing dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this fiddle?

http://jsfiddle.net/rMrSU/

HTML

Enabled

```
<select class="dropdown">
    <option value="0">Disabled</option>
    <option value="1">Enabled</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dropdown option').each(function(){
        if($(this).text()==$('div#show').text())
            $(this).attr('selected','selected');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How about [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kNRev/)

HTML

```
<select class="dropdown">
    <option value="0">Disabled</option>
    <option value="1">Enabled</option>
</select>

<div id="myId">Enabled</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('.dropdown option:contains(' + $('#myId').text() + ')').attr('selected', true);
```

or better yet [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kNRev/1/)

```
$('.dropdown').val($('.dropdown option:contains(' + $('#myId').text() + ')').val())
```

The difference between the two is that one is assigning the selected attribute (but this means there could be more that 1 item with `selected="selected"`).
The second one is better since it assigns the value to the dropdown.

It all depends how you need to access the dropdown... personnally I would go with `.val()`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something Like this :

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/eXbFg/

if the Div have "enabled", it will select option which is "Enabled"

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear... Similar to this functionality?

http://jsfiddle.net/eXbFg/

Mind you, you can use either text, or value if you feel more comfortable.