# Dynamically select from a dynamically generated dropdown

Tags: php, html, select, drop-down-menu

I have a dynamically generated dropdown list -  list of course identifiers and names.  On the basis of a variable, “assigned_course_id”, I would like to preselect the appropriate value from the dropdown list.  My best attempt is as follows.  Thanks in advance for your assistance.

```
<select name="course_id" id="course_id">
  <?php
       $assigned_course_id = $assignment['course_id'];
       foreach($courses as $course) { ?>
       <option value="<?= $course['course_id']?><?php if ($assigned_course_id == $course['course_id']) echo "selected";  ?>"><?= $course['course_name'] ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its typographical error question which is not useful for future visitor

Comment: possible duplicate of [changing dropdown option SELECTED dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733990/changing-dropdown-option-selected-dynamically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you aren't ending the `value` attribute, so your selected option becomes `<option value="optionvalueselected"` -- 'optionvalue' being the value of your selected option, and 'selected' being the attribute you want to set, but won't be set because you never ended `value`

The following should work:

```
<select name="course_id" id="course_id">
  <?php
       $assigned_course_id = $assignment['course_id'];
       foreach($courses as $course) { ?>
       <option value="<?= $course['course_id']?>" <?php if ($assigned_course_id == $course['course_id']) { echo "selected"; } ?>><?= $course['course_name'] ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Outstanding Mark!  Worked like a charm! Thanks for the lesson mate!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the work

```
<select name="course_id" id="course_id">
      <?php
           $assigned_course_id = $assignment['course_id'];
           foreach($courses as $course) { 
            $selected = "";
           if ($assigned_course_id == $course['course_id']) {
              $selected =  "selected";
           }
           echo '<option value="'.$course['course_id'].'" '.$selected.'> '.$course['course_name'] .'</option>';
       } ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: why this will do the work and why code in question doesnt work ?

Comment: @NullPoiиteя see my answer. Explanation is in there

Comment: because there was no space as in the question. the value was concatenated to  another html attribute. it was creating a mess. besides keeping php and html separate is a good practice